I am a novice. I am trying to convert a string of text into a DATE format and use that response to UPDATE a new field called regdate
Here is a query I run to convert the string:
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(RegistrationDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    arizona_oct24_vr
Then I have tried to run the update with this query:
Update arizona_oct24_vr
set regdate=(SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(RegistrationDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM arizona_oct24_vr)
I get an error that says I cannot use the table arizona_oct24_vr in the FROM statement.
I was expecting the regdate column to be updated to the DATE converted from the string in RegistrationDate.

The problem here was that there were three different forms of the date(time) string included in the Registration Date column:

MM/DD/YYYY
MM/DD/YYYY H:mm:ss
MM/DD/YYYY H:mm

The first step was to use replace to get rid of the time portion of the string.  I used this query (or versions thereof) to get rid of the TIME:
UPDATE arizona_oct24_vr
SET RegistrationDate = REPLACE (RegistrationDate, '0:00:00', '');

NOTE: REPLACE was done with UPDATE and REPLACE is case sensitive.
Then, to convert the text date into a DATE in my regdate column, I used this query:
UPDATE arizona_oct24_vr
SET regdate=DATE(STR_TO_DATE(RegistrationDate, '%m/%d/%Y'))

